# JSON TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json

i already make this JSON. but i found this error

```
 a +="<div class=\"back\">"
                + "<a href=\"[[--CatAddress, s_tk, tplid:8270--]]\"><img src=\"[[--ImgRootDir--]]resource/image/button_back.png\" width=\"85px\" /></a>"
                + "</div>"

                + "<div class=\"bg\">"
                + "<img src=\"[[--ImgRootDir--]]resource/image/Film_Level.png\" width=\"590px\" height=\"600px\" />"
                + "</div>"

                + "<div class=\"lvle\">"
                + "<table width=\"84%\">"
                + "<tr>"
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[0].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_0"),0)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[1].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_1"),1)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[2].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_2"),2)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[3].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_3"),3)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[4].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_4"),4)
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_0"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_1"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_2"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_3"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_4"))
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[5].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_5"),5)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[6].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_6"),6)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[7].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_7"),7)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[8].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_8"),8)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[9].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_9"),9)
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_5"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_6"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_7"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_8"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_9"))
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[10].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_10"),10)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[11].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_11"),11)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[12].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_12"),12)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[13].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_13"),13)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[14].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_14"),14)
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_10"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_11"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_12"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_13"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_14"))
                + "</tr>"
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[15].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_15"),15)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[16].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_16"),16)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[17].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_17"),17)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[18].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_18"),18)
                + getSubsHTML(nodes[19].image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_19"),19)
                + "</tr>"
                + "<tr>"
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_15"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_16"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_17"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_18"))
                + getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_19"))
                + "</tr>"
                + "</table>"
                + "</div>"

                + "<div class=\"left\">"
                + "<img src=\"[[--ImgRootDir--]]resource/image/Camera_kiri.png\" width=\"150px\" />"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div class=\"right\">"
                + "<img src=\"[[--ImgRootDir--]]resource/image/Camera_kanan.png\" width=\"150px\" />"
                + "</div>";
```

and this is the json

```
nodes: [
{
id: "2014_2012.json_0_0",
image: "_1396278834_af_org.png",
question: "1. What is this ?",
answer: "EXX",
hint: "asdadsadsadasdasdaads"
},
{
id: "2014_2012.json_0_0",
image: "_1396278834_af_org.png",
question: "1. What is this ?",
answer: "EXX",
hint: "asdadsadsadasdasdaads"
},
```

Comment: If you only have 2 items then it cannot find nodes[2] and on

Comment: i have many items, but still cannot read 'image'

Comment: There is not enough context here for us to tell you where your error is; however, there are a lot of places where you could improve your code style to make this easier to maintain. For example, looping over the items in nodes, and operating on those indexes, instead of copy/pasting the same function(s) 20+ times.

Comment: Please create a  fiddle

Comment: @mawlynx [Here's](https://eval.in/203060) a very rough example of what I'm talking about - you can ignore most of the initial `var`, it's largely just there to make eval.in not complain about the missing functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, made some assumptions but this worked: http://jsfiddle.net/sp1nf731/3/

Are you referencing your json variable correctly?

```
var x = { nodes: [
{
id: "2014_2012.json_0_0",
image: "_1396278834_af_org.png",
question: "1. What is this ?",
answer: "EXX",
hint: "asdadsadsadasdasdaads"
},
{
id: "2014_2012.json_0_0",
image: "_1396278834_af_org.png",
question: "1. What is this ?",
answer: "EXX",
hint: "asdadsadsadasdasdaads"
} 
] };

console.log( x.nodes[1].image );
```

This works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you get nodes, but if inline you need

```
var nodes=[
  { .... },
  { .... },
  { .... }
]; // no comma on the last
```

Here is a suggestion to shorten your code in jQuery

```
$(function() {
  var $rowa=$("<tr/>"), $rowb=$("<tr/>"),
  $.each(nodes,function(i,node) {
    if (i>0 && i%5==0) {
      $("#table1 tbody").append($rowa).append($rowb);
    }
    $rowa.append(getSubsHTML(node.image, jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_"+i),i);
    $rowb.append(getStageHTML(jsonStage.indexOf("2014_2012.json_0_"+i));
  });        
  // here you may test if i%5 !=0  and add the last rows
});
```